# SIMD intrinsics: _mm_stream_load_si128 vs _mm_load_si128

Tags: c++, intrinsics

When should i use the streaming version and when the SSE2 vs _mm_load_si128? What is the performance trade-off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The streaming load intrinsic (`mm_stream_load_si128`) performs the load "using a non-temporal memory hint" (according to the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=load_si128&expand=5191,3063)).  This means that the value loaded will not cause anything to be evicted from the cache.

This is useful if you are assembling a lot of data together that you are going to operate on immediately and not look at again for a "long" time.  Most commonly this happens during streaming operations.  I have used it when I know I am performing a simple operation on a large data set, where I know the data will quickly get evicted from the cache anyway.  Operations such as `memcpy` also fall under this category.

The non-streaming load (`mm_load_si128`) will retrieve the value and it will be subject to normal caching rules.  It may evict old cache entries if needed, and will be able to be retrieved from the cache until it is evicted.

If you expect to use the data again before a normal cache eviction would occur, then the non-streaming load is preferred.  If you are operating on a large data set where a given piece of data is not expected to be accessed again before it would have been kicked out of the cache, the streaming load is preferred.

Comment: I don’t understand, why is this beneficial for memcpy of other code that access continuous blocks or RAM? Cache line is 64 bytes = 4x __m128i, i.e. having it cached speeds up the next 3 loads by a huge factor?

Comment: Based on last comment from an old topic on that matter: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/597075
Assuming CPU optimizes such a read at all the data is loaded into a cache line-size buffer, which is separate from the data cache.
There is not many of these buffers available so best when the content of the buffer is read in subsequent instructions otherwise it might be lost and needed to be reacquired with potentially big performance penalty.

And the copying itself will not be faster than with cached memory - but will not evict entire working set from cache.